# Animate View Background Changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I have a view I change the background of as the state of the application changes. Basically I want the view background changes to animate in some sort of a slide. I've been looking for a solution, but haven't really found anything.

So I want to have a transition from whatever the current background is to the next one.

```
//current to:
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```

I have no trouble getting the background to change but I would like to animate it. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: create the `UIView` as a subview of `self.view` and do the animation for that view

Comment: please check the answers and do accept the one which helps you

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 
delay:0 
options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse                
animations:^
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
}
completion:nil 
];
```

Answer (score 1):

a very easy way to handle it:

such as `yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Then use this to animate change the color

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

yourView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
CATransition *transiton = [[CATransition alloc] init];
transiton.duration = .5;
[yourView.layer addAnimation:transiton forKey:@"Animation"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple animation block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:time animations^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColorWithPatternImage:image];
}];
```

this just animates the transfer, taking *time* seconds.